# Strftime on datetime column from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strftime

I am have a instance variable `ride` that comes from a table and it has a column `ride.pickup_at`

If I do `<%= ride.pickup_at.class.name %>` I get

> time

So Strftime should be available.

Now, if I do `<%= ride.pickup_at.strftime('%x') %>` I get an error

> undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

What do I have to do to make strftime available?

Comment: It looks like you need to set a default value for `ride.pickup_at`, maybe in a `before_create` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `try` to do the `nil` judge: `<%= ride.pickup_at.try(:strftime, '%x') %>` .Or I think you should figure out what to do if `ride.pickup_at` is `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a if condition like this before your code like this.
    <%if !ride.pickup_at.nil? %>
    <%= ride.pickup_at.strftime('%x') %>
    <% end %>
This might be because of some record having nil value for pickup_at